# How to make auto search without pressing the search button

Tags: javascript, python, html, search

I want to create a search function where if I enter some words, it can automatically display the corresponding results of those words without pressing the search button. Here's the html script that I made:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="landingtext text-center" style="margin-top: -450pt; color: aliceblue;">
     <h1>#SearchBook,<br> Search your book</h1>
  </div>
    
  <br>
  <main style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="display: inline-block;">
    <form action="{% url 'search:search' %}" autocomplete="off" method="GET">
       <input type="search" id="textInput" onkeyup="callSearchAPI(event)" name="q"         placeholder="Search your book..." value="{{search}}"> 
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light">Search</button>
    </form>

    <div class = "dropdown" id="dropdown">
                        
    </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>

<div class="container text-center">
    {% for data in data %}
    <div class="book-wrapper text-center">
        <div class="coverpage">
            <img src="{{ data.book_cover}}"/>
        </div>
        <a>{{ data.book_title|text_short }}...</a>
        <p> {{ data.stock }} </p>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if data|length > 0 %}
    <div class="d-pagination">
        <ul class="pagination">
        {% if data.has_previous %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page=1">First</a>
            </li>                               
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ data.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        {% for ord in data.paginator.page_range %}
            {% if data.number == ord %}
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <span class="page-link">{{ ord }}
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                    </span>
                </li>
            {% elif ord > data.number|add:'-3' and ord < data.number|add:'3' %}
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ ord }}">{{ ord }}</a>
                </li>

            {% endif %}

        {% endfor %}
        {% if data.has_next %}
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ data.next_page_number }}">Next</a>
            </li>
            <li class="page-item">
                <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ data.paginator.num_pages }}">Last</a>
            </li>
        {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <h3 class="text-center mt-5">Not found.</h3>
    {% endif %} 
</div>
```

The following script in the views.py app file:

```
def index(request):
    books_ = Bookk.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(books_, 20)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    books = paginator.get_page(page)
    
    context = {
        "data": books,
    }
    return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

I expect that when I enter a word in the search field, the book data will automatically appear below it without pressing the search button.

Comment: This is not a Django question, this is a JavaScript question. Use typing events in JS to call the search endpoint in Django.

Comment: @Ramesh-X Oh sorry, I thought that would affect django. do you know of a solution?